# Be notified when Service is started

Tags: android, service

I have a `Service` that scans for BLE devices. The `Activity` should show some data gathered by the `Service`.

A `Receiver` has been implemented, to be notified when the `Bluetooth` is enabled, so that we know when to start the `Service`.

If the `Service` is running, and the `Activity` is opened, it just executes `bindService()`. However, if the `Service` isn't running (because the `Bluetooth` is disabled), the App is opened and the `Bluetooth` is enabled, it won't `bind` because the binding process has already been skipped.

How can I be notified about the `Service` starting or automatically binding when started?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [LocalBroadCastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)  to send a broadCast from your service to your activity.

> Helper to register for and send broadcasts of Intents to local objects within your process. This has a number of advantages over sending global broadcasts with sendBroadcast(Intent):

Answer (score 0):

You can use localbroadcast reciever from your service.

Answer (score 0):

In your service use these code

```
    intent = new Intent("my-integer");
    intent.putExtra("message",""+a);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In your activity use this code

```
 private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Extract data included in the Intent
        String data = intent.getStringExtra("message");
           if (!data.equals("0")) {
             //Do something
           } else {
             //Do something else 
           }
        }

    }
};
```